# Can't limit mdadm's detection

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, initramfs

I've got a problem with mdadm and generating initrd.

I had some problems with one disk, so suddenly mdadm started detecting my raid1 arrays to be on hda, hdb2, hdb3 - even though they should really be on hda+hdb1, hda+hdb2, hda+hdb3. The system boots up from hdb3 without problems if I leave the mdadm to do raid autodetection (but each array uses only 1 drive of course). The problem starts when I want to disable the broken parts of the array to boot correctly and fix it. I created a file like this:

```
DEVICE /dev/hdb*
ARRAY /dev/md0 devices=/dev/hdb1 ...
ARRAY /dev/md1 devices=/dev/hdb2 ...
ARRAY /dev/md2 devices=/dev/hdb3 ...
```

but when I run `update-initramfs -u`, I get a message that the root is on `/dev/md2` and it's not defined in my `mdadm.conf`. What could be wrong there? I can clearly see that the array is defined...

Answer (score 1):

Launch the commands:

```
mdadm --fail /to/faileddevice
mdadm --zero-superblock /to/faileddevice
```

and then read the result